# Issues loading CSV into BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

Im trying to create a `BigQuery` table using a pretty simple csv file I have stored in `GCS`.
I keep getting the same error over and over again:

```
Could not parse '1/1/2008' as datetime for field XXX
```

I've checked that the csv file isn't corrupted, and I've managed to upload everything into one column so the file is readable by `BigQuery`.

I've added the word `NULL` to any empty fields thinking consecutive delimiters may be causing the issues but I am still facing the same issue.

I know data, I understand data and CSV files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery cannot cast  '1/1/2008' as DATETIME and rather would expecting something like '2008-1-1'

So, you can either modify your CSV file or just use STRING for that XXX field and than translate it into DATETIME in your queries - like below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d/%m/%Y', '1/1/2008')
```

Comment: thanks SO much, thats what was wrong!!  It would been helpful if google had had that somewhere :(.

Comment: please check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime-type and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_datetime and then just walk around - it is great amount of documentation that Google has there :o)

Comment: I knew that was going to happen as soon as I said they didnt have any documentation on it.  I had tried to find it, but I wasn't looking for the right things.  Thanks again, MUCH appreciated!

Comment: sure, come back and ask when help needed!