# Why does BigQuery fail to parse dd/mm/yyyy as date when schema is passed but works with auto-detect?

Tags: google-bigquery

I understand my question is similar to some others out there ([Issues loading CSV into BigQuery table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039079/issues-loading-csv-into-bigquery-table) for example) but can somebody give some details around this?

If I specify a schema for a dd/mm/yyyy field I get 'Could not parse '01/01/2019' as date for field' but when auto-detection is on the field gets accurately detected and parsed as a date?
Is that because auto-detection scans a number of rows and spots what the position of the month is whereas just saying it's a date in the schema means BQ can't work out where the month is for dates such as '01/01/2019'?

Answer (score 0):

DATE type expects the date written in its [canonical format](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#canonical-format): YYYY-[M]M-[D]D. That's why you get the 'Could not parse 01/01/2019' error. Anyhow, there is a workaround to [parse a given date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) if you know its format. Auto-detect must be using this function:

```
PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', '01/01/2019')
```

If you check the format in which the date is written in your table after being recognized by auto-detect, it is in the canonical one.